# React Native App - Display chars instead symbols from database

Tags: android, database, wordpress, react-native

I have a WordPress website and React Native App. These two project are connected via API Key. When I add product from the WordPress admin panel and title of that product is **Small & Big Glass** on site I have clean title of the product on the product page and display all product pages. When I say clean I mean what I write I display that, but when I open my React Native App I have a problem with displaying symbols **&** instead that symbol I have **& # 0 3 8;**. How to resolve this problem?

I didn't try with other symbols I need solution for now only for this one.

Thanks all for help.

Comment: Did you try to use :   JSON.stringify($data)

Comment: No, because I don't know what to change because I get the title from the database, not from a file placed somewhere in the app folder. @Timmy

Comment: So you try to add title inside JSON.stringify and see if you get it correct:  JSON.stringify($title)

Comment: okay, so JSON.stringify($title) is to decode any special characters from the database? I'm I, right? @Timmy

Comment: This converts character to string whether is symbol, letter or number